# Entity Framework: Get Entity Associated with DbCommandTree

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to do some work with the `EFProviderWrapperToolkit`
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx

In my derived `DbCommandWrapper`, is there any way to get the associated entity in the `ObjectStateManager` if the `DbCommandTree` in question is a `DbModificationCommandTree`?

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
if (base.Definition.CommandTree is DbModificationCommandTree)
{
   var targetEntity = ((DbModificationCommandTree)base.Definition.CommandTree).TargetEntity; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `CreateDbCommandDefinition` of `DbProviderServices` has two parameters: `DbProviderManifest manifest, DbCommandTree commandTree`.

`commandTree` can be `DbInsertCommandTree`, `DbUpdateCommandTree` or `DbDeleteCommasndTree`.

So you can detect is it modification command or not.

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think it is possible - it is layered architecture and low level layer don't have to know anything about upper layer.

Comment: I figured that might be the case....is there at least a way I can get the order that the statements will be generated in with relation to the ObjectStateEntries?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be able to get some useful information from the `Target` property of `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbModificationCommandTree`.

In particular, for an update statement you may see the following structure associated with the `Target` property if you drill down a bit:

```
Target (DbExpressionBinding)
 - Expression (DbScanExpression)
    - Target (System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase)
       - Name (string)
```

The Name refers to the name of the entity set in your entity container.

Similarly, you could examine the `Predicate` property of `DbUpdateCommandTree` or `DbDeleteCommandTree` to determine the key of the affected entity.  For an entity with an integer column Id for a primary key, this structure could look like:

```
Predicate (DbComparisonExpression)
 - Left (DbPropertyExpression)
    - Property (EdmMember)
       - Name: "Id"
 - Right (DbConstantExpression)
    - Value: 1
```

Keep in mind that the value might be a parameter reference instead of a constant and that entities with composite keys would have more complex predicates.

Once you've extracted the entity set name and key information, you can construct an `EntityKey` and get the state by calling `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(key)`.

Obviously this approach relies on knowledge of how entity framework constructs its command trees and doesn't extend well beyond simple statements.  Using `DbExpressionVisitor` to focus on particularly important structural components of the tree may help.